# MaterialTimePicker requires user to click three times

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, material-design

I am developing a native Android application with Kotlin, currently attempting to use a [MaterialTimePicker](https://material.io/components/time-pickers) to populate the time for an EditText. I have a UX issue where the user is required to click three time for the keyboard to display.

1. First click displays the MaterialTimePicker:
   [First click displays the MaterialTimePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDBRB.png)
2. Second click focuses the MaterialTimePicker:
   [Second click focuses the MaterialTimePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40rXt.png)
3. Third click displays the keyboard:
   [Third click displays the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmmqU.png)

Here is the code that handles the onClick listener for the EditText:

```
binding.startTimeTextInputEditText.setOnClickListener {
        val (hours, minutes) = Functions.getTimeSplit(binding.startTimeTextInputEditText.text.toString())
        val picker = setupTimePicker(hours, minutes, R.string.title_start_time, false)
    }
```

Here is the code that sets up and displays the MaterialTimePicker:

```
private fun setupTimePicker(
    hours: Int,
    minutes: Int,
    titleTime: Int,
    force24Hours: Boolean
): MaterialTimePicker {
    val isSystem24Hour = is24HourFormat(this)
    val clockFormat = if (!force24Hours) {
        if (isSystem24Hour) TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H else TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H
    } else {
        TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H
    }

    val picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
        .setTimeFormat(clockFormat)
        .setTitleText(titleTime)
        .setInputMode(INPUT_MODE_KEYBOARD)
        .setHour(hours)
        .setMinute(minutes)
        .build()
    picker.show(supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())

    return picker
}
```

I have already tried things such as making the EditText not focusable:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Here is the XML code for the EditText:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/startTimeTextInputLayout"
                        style="@style/TextInput.Dark"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/errorAppearance"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/Hint.Dark">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/startTimeTextInputEditText"
                            style="@style/TextInputEditText.NotClickable.Dark"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/background_rounded_input_text"
                            android:hint="@string/hint_start_time"
                            android:inputType="text" />

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

All I would like to achieve the same flow with just two clicks:

1. For the user to click on the EditText, the MaterialTimePicker to display.
2. Another click to select either the Hours or Minutes and start typing on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this two click requirement myself and it seems that it was a bug in the material-components-android library. The issue has been fixed in version [1.5.0-alpha05](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/e906367de5588ec3e22827b84a56ae0e06370f35).

So updating the library dependency to version 1.5.0-alpha05 or newer should fix your issue.

Comment: Wow I am so used to Android Studio telling me when to update imports that didn't even cross my mind. I have now updated and it works! That's awesome, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Material Components version to atleast [1.6.0-alpha01](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.6.0-alpha01). It will show the keyboard right away if you click either the Hour or Minute field

Comment: Just did, it worked! Thank you :)